# DNAT for connecting a subnet via proxy to the internet

Tags: iptables, proxy, dnat, masquerade

DNAT for connecting a subnet via proxy to the internet

I want to connect a server in a subnet to the internet via a proxy-server. But I can’t ping a host on the internet (www). 
Actually the subnet-server and the proxy-server share a common dedicated server  (virtualization with docker). There are two network-cards (eth0 for the proxy-server and t39 for the subnet-server). So the general layout goes like this:

Internet <==> 171.16.0.39 | 191.167.1.1 <==> 191.167.1.2

191.167.1.2 is the internal address of the subnet-server, while 171.16.0.39 is the external address and 191.167.1.1 is the internal address of the proxy-server.

First, I have set a static route at the subnet-server with:
`ip route add 171.16.0.39 via 191.167.1.1`

Question 1: Do I additionally need to explicitly define a default gateway like this? 
`route add default gw 191.167.1.1 eth0`
Or would choosing the external address be the right approach?

Then I have set a Masquerade in the iptable of the proxy-server:
`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`

Now can ping from the subnet-server to the proxy-server. But I cannot ping from the proxy-server to the internet (for example 8.8.8.8).

To solve my problem, I also consider establishing DNAT somewhat like this (on proxy-server):
`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 171.16.0.39 -j DNAT --to-destination    191.167.1.2`

But doesn’t solve my problems. I still cannot ping from the subnet-server to the internet.

Question 3: Do I need to configure DNAT in conjunction with the MASQUERADE to ping the internet? If so, have I choosen the wrong address?

Finally I have heard, that SNAT is not necessary in presence of a MASQUERADE configuration.

Question 4: Is it advisable to configure SNAT, even if I have already set MASQUERADE?

I’m really confused, how to handle this. Although it seems to be a pretty common configuration, my research on Google during the last couple of days didn’t got me any closer to solve the problem.

Has anyone some hints concerning my questions?

Comment: Why the weird ip scheme? That breaks things in some situations

Comment: Did you enable `net.ipv4.ip_forward` by sysctl ?

Comment: Good point, IP forwarding happens to be active.

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed the problem:

As I already guessed, I had to set a separate gateway-entry on 191.167.1.2 with:
`route add default gw 191.167.1.1`

Now I connected the subnet-server to the www via the proxy while MASQUERADE is active.